# Zend framework You don't have permission to access js/ckeditor/ **

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, zend-framework, ckeditor

I want to integrated ckeditor with my form 
I download ckeditor library from `http://ckeditor.com/download`

And followed instruction from here

```
http://golearnphp.com/zend-framework-how-to-add-fckeditor-to-a-zend_form/
```

I copied ckeditor folder in public/js/ckeditor folder but  when trying to access js file

`You don't have permission to access /ZendTecAdmin/public/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js`

error thrown.

My `.htaccess` is as below

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
```

Please help to resolve this. Thank you.

Comment: i don't think it's a `.htaccess` error

Comment: I am able to access files from js folder but not from js/ckeditor

Comment: so possibly you don't have the access permissions for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i think you need to give all access permissions to folder,

try that one first , otherwise make a folder name it includes and inside create `ckeditor` folder,
then put all the files into that folder.

change your `js` path accordingly as `includes/ckeditor.`

Then it'll work..

Comment: I changed permission all files under html folder chmod -R 777 .      Now I am able to access ckeditors files but ckeditor is not displaying in web form, How to troubleshoot this.

Comment: for that follow the tutorial you used, or you will find many others, if you still have problem  post as another question. this question's purpose has been served.